# Directive behavior changes when defining isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive for a javascript grid library slickgrid.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KWZ9i767ycz49hZZGswB?p=preview

What I want to do is pass the selected row back up the controller. So I want to use isolated scope (using the '=') to get two-way binding working between the controller and directive.

Everything works if I define the directive without any sort of scope declaration:

```
<slickgrid id="myGrid" data="names" selected-item="selectedItem"></slickgrid>

app.directive('slickgrid', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  //scope: {
  //  selectedItem: '='
  //},
  template: '<div></div>',
  link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
   ...
    var redraw = function(newScopeData) {
    grid.setData(newScopeData);
    grid.render();
};
$scope.$watch(attrs.data, redraw, true);
```

But if I uncomment the lines above (lines 19-21 in app.js) it looks like the $scope.$watch which is watching the attrs.data object is calling redraw but the attrs.data is being passed in as undefined.

My analysis could be wrong, but I'm not sure why defining the scope would cause this. Can someone explain why that might be?

.nathan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define an isolate scope, then any $watch in your directive will be looking for whatever `attrs.data` evaluates to on your isolate scope.  `attrs.data` evaluates to the string `names`, so the $watch is looking for `$scope.names` on your isolate scope, which doesn't exist.  (Without the isolate scope, the directive uses the same scope as MainCtrl, and `$scope.names` exists there.)

To use an isolate scope, you'll need to define another isolate scope property to pass in `names`:

```
scope: {
  selectedItem: '=',
  data: '='
},
...
$scope.$watch('data', redraw, true);
```

The HTML can remain the same.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get this to work. However, I'm still unclear why the data scope needs to be encapsulated in ticks. Now I have to figure out why the {{selectedItem}} isn't updating when a new row is selected in the directive!

Comment: @nathasm, if the first argument to [$watch](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) is a string, then it is evaluated against the scope, just like `ng-click='someProperty = 22'` or `ng-model='someProperty'` or `ng-show="showIt"`.  To get `{{selectedItem}}` to update: `$scope.selectedItem = item; $scope.$apply()`.  [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SJUJkgb4GgDwNlnJElBk?p=preview).